# Pandas how to apply multiple functions to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to apply a list of functions to each column in a DataFrame like the DataFrameGroupBy.agg function does?  I found an ugly way to do it like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(one=np.random.uniform(0,10,100), two=np.random.uniform(0,10,100)))
df.groupby(np.ones(len(df))).agg(['mean','std'])

        one                 two
       mean       std      mean       std
1  4.802849  2.729528  5.487576  2.890371
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For Pandas 0.20.0 or newer, use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) (thanks to ayhan for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128218/pandas-how-to-apply-multiple-functions-to-dataframe/22128316?noredirect=1#comment85010010_22128316)):

```
In [11]: df.agg(['mean', 'std'])
Out[11]: 
           one       two
mean  5.147471  4.964100
std   2.971106  2.753578
```

For older versions, you could use

```
In [61]: df.groupby(lambda idx: 0).agg(['mean','std'])
Out[61]: 
        one               two          
       mean       std    mean       std
0  5.147471  2.971106  4.9641  2.753578
```

Another way would be:

```
In [68]: pd.DataFrame({col: [getattr(df[col], func)() for func in ('mean', 'std')] for col in df}, index=('mean', 'std'))
Out[68]: 
           one       two
mean  5.147471  4.964100
std   2.971106  2.753578
```

Comment: `agg` is now available as a DataFrame method so this works without the trick too: `df.agg(['mean', 'std'])`.

Comment: I have notice that using agg is a lot slower than just applying a function in the df. i.e df.sum(), df. mean() instead of df.agg(['sum'], 'mean']). is there a reason for that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @saias: It might be worth asking this as a new question. My guess is that `df.agg(['sum','mean'])` ultimately calls [`pandas.core.base.SelectionMixin._aggregate`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L301) which handles many different cases for input and output. All that extra case handling slows down the performance of `df.agg`. In this case, you can bypass a lot of that code by building the desired DataFrame yourself with something like `pd.DataFrame({'sum':df.sum(), 'mean':df.mean()}).T`.

Answer (score 16):

In the general case where you have arbitrary functions and column names, you could do this:

```
df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'mean': r.mean(), 'std': r.std()})).transpose()

         mean       std
one  5.366303  2.612738
two  4.858691  2.986567
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to apply three functions into a column and it works

```
#removing new line character
rem_newline = lambda x : re.sub('\n',' ',x).strip()

#character lower and removing spaces
lower_strip = lambda x : x.lower().strip()

df = df['users_name'].apply(lower_strip).apply(rem_newline).str.split('(',n=1,expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using pandas to analyze Chilean legislation drafts. In my dataframe, the list of authors are stored as a string. The answer above did not work for me (using pandas 0.20.3). So I used my own logic and came up with this:

```
df.authors.apply(eval).apply(len).sum()
```

Concatenated applies! A pipeline!! The first apply transforms

```
"['Barros Montero: Ramón', 'Bellolio Avaria: Jaime', 'Gahona Salazar: Sergio']"
```

into the obvious list, the second apply counts the number of lawmakers involved in the project. I want the size of every pair (lawmaker, project number) (so I can presize an array where I will study which parties work on what).

Interestingly, this works! Even more interestingly, that last call fails if one gets too ambitious and does this instead:

```
df.autores.apply(eval).apply(len).apply(sum)
```

with an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

coming from deep within /site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply