# Combining different functions into One , Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, apply

I need to combine different functions into one and use the apply function(of those individual functions) within the main function itself. My case is something more complex so i'll use a basic example for this.

Suppose i have a data consisting of numbers. Lets call it "MathData". The column containing the 2 numbers is called 'digits'.

Here are my individual functions:

```
def add(nm1,nm2):
    sum = nm1+nm2
    return sum
MathData['sum'] = Mathdata['digits'].apply(add) #gives me new column called "sum" with the sum of each observation in it.
```

Similarly,

```
def diff(nm1,nm2):
    subtract = nm1-nm2
    return subtract

def mul(nm1,nm2):
    multiply = nm1 * nm2
    return multiply

def div(nm1,nm2):
    divide = nm1/nm2
    return divide


MathData['difference'] = Mathdata['digits'].apply(diff)
MathData['product'] = Mathdata['digits'].apply(mul)
MathData['quotient'] = Mathdata['digits'].apply(div)
```

So I'd get different columns with the sum, diff,product,quotient etc.
I want all of these into 1 function with each value in different columns.

```
def mathop(nm1,nm2):
    sum = nm1+nm2
    diff = nm1-nm2
    mul = nm1*nm2
    div = nm1/nm2
    return sum,diff,mul,div
```

The above function would give me all values in a single column separated by commas. is there a way to apply each one in such a way that they come under different columns??

Comment: See related post, you should be able to use the answer to achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128218/pandas-how-to-apply-multiple-functions-to-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the `pandas` module, but in pure Python you could do something like this:

```
import operator
mathops = {'sum': operator.sum,
           'diff': operator.sub,
           'mul': operator.mul,
           'div': operator.div}

for op_name, op in mathops:
    MathData[op_name] = MathData['digits'].apply(op)
```