# How to apply multiple functions to a pandas dataframe without multiple loops?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, apply

I use pandas for an ETL process. I query a database I put the result in a dataframe; the dataframe is pretty big (1M rows * 50 columns). The dataframe is mainly composed of string and date.

I use the `apply()` function of pandas to make all my transformations. The thing is my transformation contains multiple branching on string.

```
df['merged_contract_status'] = df.apply(lib.merged_contract_status, axis=1) 
df['renewed'] = df.apply(lib.contract_renewed, axis=1)
df['renewal_dt'] = df.apply(lib.contract_renewed_date, axis=1)
....
```

I have a bunch of transformation like that.
The functions I call:

```
def merged_contract_status(row):
    if row['tbm_contract_status'] is not np.nan:
        mergedContractStatus = row['tbm_contract_status']
    else:
        mergedContractStatus = row['ccn_status']

    return mergedContractStatus

def contract_renewed(row):
    ccn_activation_dt = row['ccn_activation_dt']
    ccn_status = row['ccn_status']
    f_init_val_dt = row['f_init_val_dt']
    f_nat_exp_dt = row['f_nat_exp_dt']
    spr_spo_code = row['spr_spo_code']  
    csp_status_sep_1 = row['csp_status_sep_1']
    csp_begin_dt_sep_1 = row['csp_begin_dt_sep_1']
    ctt_type_1 = row['ctt_type_1']  
    csp_status_sep_2 = row['csp_status_sep_2']
    csp_begin_dt_sep_2 = row['csp_begin_dt_sep_2']
    ctt_type_2 = row['ctt_type_2']  
    csp_status_sep_3 = row['csp_status_sep_3']
    csp_begin_dt_sep_3 = row['csp_begin_dt_sep_3']
    ctt_type_3 = row['ctt_type_3']
    csp_begin_dt_sep_father = row['csp_begin_dt_sep_father']
    csp_end_dt_sep_father = row['csp_end_dt_sep_father']
    todayDate = datetime.datetime.today()       

    if spr_spo_code == 'PCC':       
        if ctt_type_1 == 'NORMAL' and ccn_activation_dt is not None and csp_begin_dt_sep_1 is not None and csp_begin_dt_sep_1>(ccn_activation_dt+timedelta(365)):
            return 'Y'
        elif ctt_type_2 == 'NORMAL' and ccn_activation_dt is not None and csp_begin_dt_sep_2 is not None and csp_begin_dt_sep_2>(ccn_activation_dt+timedelta(365)):
            return 'Y'
        elif ctt_type_3== 'NORMAL' and ccn_activation_dt is not None and csp_begin_dt_sep_3 is not None and csp_begin_dt_sep_3>(ccn_activation_dt+timedelta(365)):
            return 'Y'
        else:
            return 'N'
    else:
        if (f_init_val_dt is None and f_nat_exp_dt is None and 
            ccn_activation_dt is not None and 
            ccn_activation_dt < (todayDate- timedelta(365)) and 
            (csp_begin_dt_sep_father <= todayDate and csp_begin_dt_sep_father >= todayDate and ccn_status=='ACTIVATED')):
            return 'Y'
        elif f_init_val_dt is not None and f_nat_exp_dt is not None and f_init_val_dt <= todayDate and f_nat_exp_dt >= todayDate and ccn_status=='ACTIVATED' and ccn_activation_dt is not None and ccn_activation_dt < (todayDate- timedelta(365)):
            return 'Y'
        else:
            return 'N'
```

Each time I call apply on my df, pandas loops through the entire df and it takes around 10 min. I'm OK with that 10 min; I know I cannot improve performance.
But is there a way to avoid multiple loop? Can pandas loop only once and do all the transformation I want?

EDIT: It's hard to give you data since the dataframe is big and it is built with sql query.
The help I want is a way to loop only once through the dataframe, I do not want to improve each function (taht's kind of impossible with those branching on string)

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you showed what your function is doing, some sample data, code to reproduce your df and the desired df

Comment: Perhaps a .groupby().agg() method would help?  For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128218/pandas-how-to-apply-multiple-functions-to-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Python and Pandas can only do one thing at a time. Your functions does a lot of things though and you could build them together to one function. But that is not actually your problem here.

Applying functions with `axis=1` is super heavy, because you are iterating over the whole dataframe.

You are using pandas, but you are not **using** pandas.

You should rewrite the functions you apply into vectorized operations.

It looks like the [.loc method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) could help you out a lot

Index your dataframe on anything you are using in the if statements

```
df.set_index(['spr_spo_code', 'ctt_type_1', 'ccn_activation_dt'], inplace=True)
```

and so on.

Then you can use the `.loc`, but first you should create a column where you want the result.

```
df['Contract_renewed'] = 'N'
df.loc['PCC', 'NORMAL', None ..., 'Contract_renewed'] = 'Y'
```

And this will be crazy much faster than your current way of operation.

#### Tiny example

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':['baz','boo','bee'], 'baz':['N']*3})
>>> df.set_index(['bar', 'foo'], inplace=True)
>>> df.loc[('baz', 1), 'baz'] = 'Y'
>>> df
        baz
bar foo    
baz 1     Y
boo 2     N
bee 3     N
```

Comment: Yes I agree with that and I know that. But as you can guess it's impossible to rewrite my function into vectorized operation since I deal with string.

Comment: it's not impossible. Pandas provides lots of nice vectorised operations for strings too. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/text.html#text-string-methods