# Custom describe or aggregate without groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `groupby.agg` where my group is the entire dataframe.  Put another way, I want to use the `agg` functionality, without the groupby.  I've looked for an example of this, but can not find it.

Here's what I've done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
```

[image: df]

```
def describe(df):
    funcs = dict(Kurt=lambda x: x.kurt(),
                 Skew='skew',
                 Mean='mean',
                 Std='std')
    one_group = [True for _ in df.index]
    funcs_for_all = {k: funcs for k in df.columns}
    return df.groupby(one_group).agg(funcs_for_all).iloc[0].unstack().T

describe(df)
```

[image]

#### Question

How was I supposed to have done this?

Comment: I don't think there is a better alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22128218/2285236

Comment: Thanks @ayhan.  That is helpful if not hopeful.

Comment: What about the built-in function `Dataframe.describe()`? Doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: @ysearka, Unfortunately no.  It doesn't include Skew and Kurtosis and is slower due to the excess calculations it's making.  Also, I was looking for a general solution.

Comment: This is a great question, took me a long time to find it.  I want to do the analogue of SQL's `select count(*), mean(foo) from bar` which implicitly groups over everything without an explicit groupby.  I was kind of surprised you couldn't just do `bar.agg(...)` but ended up with the same solution as below.  If it helps google, I was searching for things like "pandas agg without groupby" or "pandas groupby overall entire dataframe"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A small compaction of your own proposal, which I think improves readability, by exploiting that `DataFrame.groupby()` accepts a lambda function:

```
def describe(df):
    funcs = dict(Kurt=lambda x: x.kurt(),
                 Skew='skew',
                 Mean='mean',
                 Std='std')
    funcs_for_all = {k: funcs for k in df.columns}
    return df.groupby(lambda _ : True).agg(funcs_for_all).iloc[0].unstack().T

describe(df)
```