# Aggregate df with user defined function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, aggregate

I have a question regarding aggregating pandas dataframes with user defined functions. If i have a dataframe and run agg with or without groupby the result is aggregated when built in functions are used. If i on the other hand use a custom defined function it works as intended when groupby is used. When no groupby is used no aggregation is done. Is there a way to aggregate without a groupby and using a custom function? I know a could just add a dummy variable but that is not the prefered solution. Test1-3 work as intended but not test 4.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
n=1000
np.random.seed(0)

df['a'] = np.random.rand(n)
df['a'] = np.random.rand(n)
df['c'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=n)

def CoV(_s):
    return pd.Series({'CoV' : np.std(_s)/np.mean(_s)})

test1 = df.agg({'a':['std', np.mean]})
print(test1)

test2 = df.groupby(['c']).agg({'a':['std', np.mean]})
print(test2)

test3 = df.groupby(['c']).agg({'a':[CoV]})
print(test3)

# does not work as intended, no aggregation
test4 = df.agg({'a':[CoV]})
print(test4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired result:

```
df.assign(k=1).groupby('k')['a'].apply(CoV).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So you [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) `k` just to use it for `groupby` and then remove it by `reseting` and `droping` index.

Comment: Thanks this also works if i use cov and mean together.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers here have addressed **why** this is failing.  If you dig into the pandas code, when a UDF is passed to `df.agg`, a Series object for each column will be passed to the UDF.

In your case, using a dictionary selects a Series object (a column) and the UDF is then passed to the Series object's `Series.agg` function.  Because it is not a known function (like the string `'mean'`), it ends up being passed to `Series.apply`, which maps the function over each value in the Series object.  This is the result you are seeing.

Luckily, the passing of the UDF to `Series.apply` happens in a `try/except` block.  If it fail to to work using `Series.apply(func)`, it swaps to passing the Series object to the function via `func(Series)`.  You can use this to modify your code to raise an error if the passed object is not a Series or DataFrame.

```py
def CoV(_s):
    if not isinstance(_s, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, np.array)):
        raise TypeError()
    return pd.Series({'CoV' : np.std(_s)/np.mean(_s)})
```

Now passing it to `.agg` works as you would expect.  It is a hacky work-around, but it works.

```py
df.agg({'a': CoV})
# returns:
            a
CoV  0.584645
```

EDIT:

To get this to work with other functions, like `'mean'`, you will have to pass those as UDFs as well, unfortunately.  Even worse, the accumulation of the results is different for UDFs than for built-in functions.  Pandas simply stacks them horizontally with a hierarchical column index.  A simple `stack` and `reset_index` fixes this.

```py
def check_input(fn):
    def wrapper(_s, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(_s, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, np.array)):
            raise TypeError()
        return fn(_s, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    return wrapper

@check_input
def Mean(_s):
    return pd.Series({'Mean': np.mean(_s)})

@check_input
def CoV(_s):
    return pd.Series({'CoV' : np.std(_s)/np.mean(_s)})

df.agg({'a': [CoV, Mean], 'c': Mean}).stack().reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
# returns:
             a      c
CoV   0.584645    NaN
Mean  0.511350  2.011
```

Comment: Thanks nice solution does not work with cov and mean together though. Just for the record this would be the prefered solution because the uppdate is only in the function but it cannot handle UDF and built in function at the same time.

Comment: Thanks super informative answer. The solution is cool but it’s a little bit unfortunate that all built in functions have to be redefiened.

Comment: Yup...there is probably a way around it, just not sure from 20 minutes in the code.

Comment: Good answer, nice to see one that includes a look under the hood, especially w.r.t. passing a list of multiple func objects.

Comment: Excelent answer. One Addition: If you act on a `pd.groupby` object, you do not need to return a `pd.Series` object, instead, you can return the value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.apply()`: 
`df.apply(CoV, axis=0)`

This also works for me: 
`test4 = df.agg(CoV, axis=0)`

What you'll get is a dataframe with scalar results of the applied function:

```
            a         b         c
CoV  0.585977  0.584645  0.406688
```

Then just slice the Series you need.

**Assumptions:** You want to apply a **single** custom scalar function (Series to scalar) on different columns without group-bys .

**Edit:** If you'd like to combine multiple functions, another thing you can do is to present all of them as output of your function (which returns a `pd.Series`). For example you can rewrite your custom function as:

```
def myfunc(_s):
    return pd.Series({'mean': _s.mean(), 
                       'std': _s.std(), 
                       'CoV' : np.std(_s)/np.mean(_s)})
```

Then running this one with `.apply()` will yield multiple results.
`df.apply(myfunc)` will now give:

```
               a           b           c
mean    0.495922    0.511350    2.011000
std     0.290744    0.299108    0.818259
CoV     0.585977    0.584645    0.406688
```

See more here:
[Pandas how to apply multiple functions to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128218/pandas-how-to-apply-multiple-functions-to-dataframe)

Comment: Nice one, op can also select desired columns with `df[['a']].agg(CoV, axis=0)`.

Comment: Thanks nice solution does not work with cov and mean together though.

Comment: True, edited to include the multiple function case (interesting topic indeed) :)