# Using Python Panda aggregates operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this-

```
Hotel         Earning

Abu            1000

Zain            400

Show            500

Zint            300

Abu             500

Zain            700

Abu             500

Abu             500

Abu             800

Abu             1600

Show            1300

Zint            600
```

Using Panda, How to group by hotel and calculate the **min, median and max** of the earning on each hotel. And at the end print the aggregates values Hotel name "Abu".

Output:

```
[500.0, 650.0, 1600.0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas how to apply multiple functions to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128218/pandas-how-to-apply-multiple-functions-to-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df.groupby('Hotel').agg([('Min' , 'min'), ('Max', 'max'), ('Median', 'median')])
# Out:
#       Earning             
#           Min   Max Median
# Hotel                     
# Abu       500  1600  650.0
# Show      500  1300  900.0
# Zain      400   700  550.0
# Zint      300   600  450.0
```

For more statistics you can also use [`describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html)

```
df.groupby('Hotel').describe()
# Out: 
#       Earning                                                             
#         count        mean         std    min    25%    50%     75%     max
# Hotel                                                                     
# Abu       6.0  816.666667  435.507367  500.0  500.0  650.0   950.0  1600.0
# Show      2.0  900.000000  565.685425  500.0  700.0  900.0  1100.0  1300.0
# Zain      2.0  550.000000  212.132034  400.0  475.0  550.0   625.0   700.0
# Zint      2.0  450.000000  212.132034  300.0  375.0  450.0   525.0   600.0
```